# Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 for Raspberry Pi 3+ login loop

Tags: login

I successfully copied the disk image to a micro SD card. Then booted up the Raspberry Pi using the micro SD. Upon login the system requires a password change as expected. However once any new password is entered, a message is sent to the screen but is wiped away far too fast to read and a new login screen appears.

Over the next hour, this scenario is repeated until I finally realize that doing the same thing over and over while expecting a different result is the definition of ... well you get the picture.

Does anyone have any advise on how to get past this block and help me regain my sanity?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it looks as if there isn't a well spring of Ubuntu/Raspberry Pi experience here right now. Not surprising as I didn't find much on the topic through googling either. Any advise on where to go to find a deeper well? I'll see if I can't find out who maintains the project and  where they hang out online. I'll report back if successful.

Answer (score 2):

Try rebooting the PI. I had the same issue with a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a PI 4.  I was connecting over SSH.  It told me the password was expired and requested a new one.  It allowed me to change it, but then disconnected the session.  I could reconnect only to have it tell me my new password was expired and request I set a new one (and so on and so forth).  After rebooting the PI I was able to login normally using the newest password I had set.

Comment: Yep, this was it for me.

Comment: I think what's actually going on here is that you have SSH control masters set up on the client.  As long as the same SSH connection is open, each new session will ask you to change the password.  You can force the connection to close with `ssh ubuntu@<ip-or-name> -O exit` and then try logging in again.  This Worked For Me (TM).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but it was actually user error for me. Adding this answer if it helps anyone else.

The prompt that shows up asks for the "Current Password" NOT the "New Password". If you don't type the current password correctly the screen wipes and asks for login.

If you correctly enter the current password, then you should see a prompt for the "New Password" followed by another prompt to "Retype New Password". After that you'll be able to login with the new password.